# Delete whole line NOT containing given string

Tags: string, sed, lines, contain

Is there a way to delete the whole line if it contains specific word using sed? i.e.
I have the following:

> aaa bbb ccc
>
> qqq fff yyy
>
> ooo rrr ttt
>
> kkk ccc www

I want to delete lines that contain 'ccc' and leave other lines intact. In this example the output would be:

> qqq fff yyy
>
> ooo rrr ttt

All this using sed. Any hints?

Comment: Does the answer below solve your problem? Than you could accept it.

Answer (score 7):

```
sed -n '/ccc/!p'
```

or

```
sed '/ccc/d'
```